# Complexity of TreeSet operations

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, treeset

- What is the complexity of higher() in java.util.TreeSet?
- What would be the (amortized) complexity of accessing all elements in ascending order?

In the [description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), it only says "This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains)".

Comment: By "accessing all elements in ascending order" do you mean iterating over the set, or repeatedly calling `higher()`?

Comment: Iterating over the set. Not only all-elements case, but also any subsequence sequence (for instance, "give me the next 4 elements"). As for higher(), I need to be sure it will always be in O(logN).

Answer (score 0):

I believe higher() would be also log(n).  To find the higher element, find the location of where you would insert the input to higher(), and go "up" one, resulting in log(n) time.

If you iterate through the elements, you are looking at n time.  If you access each element buy using contains, then you are looking at n log(n) time.

Comment: Actually: contains is certain to be in log(N); and why n time?

Comment: Well if you use `log(n)` `n` times then it's `n log(n)`